# The textbox of the current Activity is not updated when another item is selected in the RadioButton of the previous Activity. Android/Java

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, methods

The application should count the moments of inertia and moments of resistance of the profiles, and output the value of the selected profile in the TextView.
Application work:

1. The user enters the value of loads, deflection, length
2. Selects the required profile via radoiButton
3. Clicks on the "Execute calculation" button
4. The application reads and displays the value of the selected profile in the TextView
   At the first launch, the application works correctly and everything is displayed. But when you exit to the previous activity to change the profile selection via radoiButton, the value of the text field does not change and remains the same as in the previous selection. Only restarting the entire application helps.
   It turns out that to change the cross-section, you need to completely terminate the application each time and re-enter the data.

data input activity1

```
public void shvellerOnClick(View view) {
 
        radioGroupShveller.removeAllViews();
 
        RadioButton shvellerYRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);
        RadioButton shvellerPRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);
 
        shvellerYRadioButton.setText(R.string.shveller_Y);
        shvellerPRadioButton.setText(R.string.shveller_P);
 
        radioGroupShveller.addView(shvellerYRadioButton);
        radioGroupShveller.addView(shvellerPRadioButton);
 
        shvellerPRadioButton.setOnClickListener(radioButtonClickListener);
        shvellerYRadioButton.setOnClickListener(radioButtonClickListener);
 
        shvellerYRadioButton.setId(R.id.idShvellerYRadioButton);
        shvellerPRadioButton.setId(R.id.idShvellerPRadioButton);
 
        radioGroupShvellerX2.removeAllViews();
        radioGroupDvutavr.removeAllViews();
 
        radioGroupShvellerX2.clearCheck();
        radioGroupDvutavr.clearCheck();
 
    }
 
    public void dvaShvelleraOnClick(View view) {
 
        radioGroupShvellerX2.removeAllViews();
 
        RadioButton shvellerYX2RadioButton = new RadioButton(this);
        RadioButton shvellerPX2RadioButton = new RadioButton(this);
 
        shvellerYX2RadioButton.setText(R.string.shveller_Y_x2);
        shvellerPX2RadioButton.setText(R.string.shveller_P_x2);
 
        radioGroupShvellerX2.addView(shvellerYX2RadioButton);
        radioGroupShvellerX2.addView(shvellerPX2RadioButton);
 
        shvellerYX2RadioButton.setOnClickListener(radioButtonClickListener);
        shvellerPX2RadioButton.setOnClickListener(radioButtonClickListener);
 
        shvellerYX2RadioButton.setId(R.id.idShvellerYX2RadioButton);
        shvellerPX2RadioButton.setId(R.id.idShvellerPX2RadioButton);
 
        radioGroupShveller.removeAllViews();
        radioGroupDvutavr.removeAllViews();
 
        radioGroupShvellerX2.clearCheck();
        radioGroupDvutavr.clearCheck();
    
    }
 
 
    View.OnClickListener radioButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)v;
            switch (rb.getId()) {
                case R.id.idShvellerYRadioButton:
                    valueSelectedGost = 0;
                    break;
                case R.id.idShvellerPRadioButton:
                    valueSelectedGost = 1;
                    break;
                case R.id.idShvellerYX2RadioButton:
                    valueSelectedGost = 10;
                    break;
                case R.id.idShvellerPX2RadioButton:
                    valueSelectedGost = 11;
                    break;
                case R.id.idDvutavBRadioButton:
                    valueSelectedGost = 20;
                    break;
                case R.id.idDvutavKRadioButton:
                    valueSelectedGost = 21;
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
 
  
    public void vypolnitRaschetOnClick(View view) {
 
        int putGost = valueSelectedGost;
 
        Intent performCalculationIntent = new Intent(StBalkaSchema1CopyActivity.this, StBalkaShema1RaschetCopyActivity.class);
 
        performCalculationIntent.putExtra("gostInt", putGost);
 
        startActivity(performCalculationIntent);
    }
```

Activity2 calculation

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int getGostInt = intent.getIntExtra("gostInt",0);
  
        selectedProfileImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selectedProfileImegeView);
        selectedProfileTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectedProfileTextView);

        infoSelectedProfileTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoSelectionProfileTextView);
 
 
        double loadToFormula = Double.parseDouble(loadTextView.getText().toString());
        double lengthToFormula = Double.parseDouble(lengthTextView.getText().toString());
        double deflectionToFormula = Double.parseDouble(deflectionTextView.getText().toString());
 
        double resultWtr = resultMmax * 100 / (1.12*2.1);
        double resultItr = resultMmax * Math.pow(10, 5) * lengthMToFormula * Math.pow(10, 2) * deflectionToFormula / (10 * 2.1 * Math.pow(10, 6));

 
        if (getGostInt >= 0 & getGostInt <= 9){
            selectedProfileImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.shveller);
            if (getGostInt == 0){
                ShvellerU_GOST_8240_89.addShvellerU();
                infoSelectedProfileTextView.setText(ShvellerU_GOST_8240_89.getClosestInertiaResistance(resultItr, resultWtr));
                selectedProfileTextView.setText(R.string.shveller_Y);
            } else if (getGostInt == 1){
                ShvellerP_GOST_8240_89.addShvellerP();
                infoSelectedProfileTextView.setText(ShvellerP_GOST_8240_89.getClosestInertiaResistance(resultItr, resultWtr));
                selectedProfileTextView.setText(R.string.shveller_P);
            }else {
                infoSelectedProfileTextView.setText("Профиль не выбран");
                selectedProfileTextView.setText("Профиль не выбран");
            }
 
        } else if (getGostInt >= 10 & getGostInt <= 19){
            selectedProfileImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dva_shvellera);
            if(getGostInt == 10){
                ShvellerUx2_GOST_8240_89.addShvellerUx2();
                infoSelectedProfileTextView.setText(ShvellerUx2_GOST_8240_89.getClosestInertiaResistance(resultItr, resultWtr));
                selectedProfileTextView.setText(R.string.shveller_Y_x2);
            } else if (getGostInt == 11){
                ShvellerPx2_GOST_8240_89.addShvellerPx2();
                infoSelectedProfileTextView.setText(ShvellerPx2_GOST_8240_89.getClosestInertiaResistance(resultItr, resultWtr));
                selectedProfileTextView.setText(R.string.shveller_P_x2);
            } else {
                infoSelectedProfileTextView.setText("Профиль не выбран");
                selectedProfileTextView.setText("Профиль не выбран");
            }
        }
  }
```

Profile adding method

```
public class ShvellerU_GOST_8240_89 extends Shveller {
 
    public ShvellerU_GOST_8240_89(String name, double momentSoprotivleniya, double momentInertsii, double massa) {
        super(name, momentSoprotivleniya, momentInertsii, massa);
    }
 
    public static void addShvellerU() {
        ShvellerU_GOST_8240_89 shveller5U = new ShvellerU_GOST_8240_89("5У", 9.1,22.8,4.84);
        shveller5U.putIn(shveller5U);
 
        ShvellerU_GOST_8240_89 shveller6_5U = new ShvellerU_GOST_8240_89("6,5У", 15,48.6,5.9);
        shveller6_5U.putIn(shveller6_5U);
 
        ShvellerU_GOST_8240_89 shveller8U = new ShvellerU_GOST_8240_89("8У", 22.4,89.4,7.05);
        shveller8U.putIn(shveller8U);
 
        ShvellerU_GOST_8240_89 shveller10U = new ShvellerU_GOST_8240_89("10У", 34.8,174.0,8.59);
        shveller10U.putIn(shveller10U);
 
    }
 
}
```

The error will most likely occur in this block activity2 calculation.

```
if (getGostInt == 0){
                ShvellerU_GOST_8240_89.addShvellerU();     
 infoSelectedProfileTextView.setText(ShvellerU_GOST_8240_89.getClosestInertiaResistance(resultItr, resultWtr));
selectedProfileTextView.setText(R.string.shveller_Y);
```

I think that this is due to the fact that when objects are added through the addShvellerU () method, they remain in memory and when a different section is selected, the addDvutavrK () method cannot overwrite another. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Show the method where you update radio button, how you save it and how you retrieve it in the next activity. You posted a whole lot of code that probably has nothing to do with the problem you are having. As is you are unlikely to get a speedy answer

Comment: I have adjusted my question on your advice